# How to fix nodejs Error Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

Im trying to install my work project app CLI

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '(HERE GOES THE DOCUMENT ROUT)'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

What should I do???? I don´t know how to solve it? :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Share screenshot please, there must be module name, if so the run

`npm install "module-name"`

in terminal.

Or you should follow these steps:-

1. Delete node_modules
2. run `npm audit --force` in a terminal.
3. now run `npm install` in a terminal.

If this works, then good, otherwise you must get the module name and then install it as I wrote earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If the module was installed via npm, but you are still getting this error, make sure that nodejs can find the node_modules dir at either $PATH or $NODE_PATH env vars.